# Is it possible to join a table and a view?

Tags: sql

I have a View "Sales" and a table "Products". Can I use normal join (inner, full, left, right, etc) to join them?

Comment: Yes. [‍](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.  Views and tables are intended to appear indistinguishable to client consumption.  Join away.